# Azure- get refresh token expiration time using CLI

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-cli

How can I get using CLI the number of hours after session token expiration that a session token can be used to call the token refresh API? Is there a way to update this setting?
I know I can use TokenRefreshExtensionHours from the sdk but I want to do it using CLI. Any idea?

Comment: take a step back, what problem are you trying to solve, not how to achieve the solution you think will solve it

Comment: Any update now? If it helps you, you could accept it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Authenticated sessions expire after 8 hours. After an authenticated session expires, there is a 72-hour grace period by default. During this grace period, the session token can be renewed in App Service without reauthenticating the user. `/.auth/refresh`You can call when your session token expires, and you don't have to track the token expiration yourself. After the 72-hour grace period, the user must sign in again to get a valid session token.

If 72 hours is not enough, you can extend this validity period. To extend the default lifetime , run the following command in [Cloud Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/cli/azure/webapp/auth?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-auth-update) :

```
az webapp auth update --resource-group <group_name> --name <app_name> --token-refresh-extension-hours <hours>
```